# What could go wrong when merging multiple GeoJSONs?

Tags: geojson, vector, ogr, ogr2ogr, ogrmerge

### Attempt I - [ogrmerge](https://gdal.org/programs/ogrmerge.html)

I have a few GeoJSONs in a directory called `jordsmonnfiles`. I want to get one GeoJSON file with the features from the files matching the pattern `jordsmonnfiles/jordsmonn_*JK1.geojson`. My first attempt:

```
python3 ogrmerge.py -f GeoJSON -o JK1.geojson -nln JK1 jordsmonnfiles/jordsmonn_*JK1.geojson
```

I get the error:

> ERROR 1: Layer JK1 already exists, and -append not specified.
> Consider using -append, or -overwrite. ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed translation of layer JK1 (use
> -skipfailures to skip errors)

I read up on the `-append` flag in the [documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/ogrmerge.html), which describes it as:

> Open an existing dataset in update mode, and if output layers already
> exist, append the content of input layers to them.

Trying it:

```
python3 ogrmerge.py -f GeoJSON -o JK1.geojson -nln JK1 jordsmonnfiles/jordsmonn_*JK1.geojson -append
```

Output:

> ERROR: -f incompatible with -update

Take away the `-f` flag then:

```
python3 ogrmerge.py -o JK1.geojson -nln JK1 jordsmonnfiles/jordsmonn_*JK1.geojson -append
```

> ERROR: Destination dataset does not exist

**How could I unite all the defined geometries in files matching the pattern `jordsmonnfiles/jordsmonn_*JK1.geojson` into a single file?**

The schematic view of the desired output would be:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "WHATEVER_NAME",
"features": [
    { "type": "Feature",
      "properties": "WHATEVER, I DON'T NEED TO PRESERVE PROPERTIES OF SOURCE FILES",
      "geometry":
        { "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[[10.0,11.2], [10.5, 11.9],[10.8, 12.0],[10.0,11.2]]] }
    },
    { "type": "Feature",
      "properties": "WHATEVER, I DON'T NEED TO PRESERVE PROPERTIES OF SOURCE FILES",
      "geometry":
        { "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[[12.0,14.2], [12.5, 14.9],[12.8, 14.0],[12.0,14.2]]] }
    },
]
}
```

I only care about geometries, not properties of each. I don't want to unite them in the sense of producing a `MultiPolygon`, but I want to list all of the geometries separately in the `features` part of the GeoJSON.

---

### Attempt II - [mapbox/geojson-merge](https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-merge)

I have also tried to use `geojson-merge`.

```
npm install -g @mapbox/geojson-merge # installs successfully
geojson-merge jordsmonnfiles/jordsmonn_*JK1.geojson > JK1.geojson
```

Output:

> /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/@mapbox/geojson-merge/geojson-merge:17
> process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(merge(argv._.map(function(n) {
> ^
>
> RangeError: Invalid string length
> at JSON.stringify ()
> at Object. (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/@mapbox/geojson-merge/geojson-merge:17:29)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
>
> Node.js v18.0.0

Comment: If you need to merge features, I have created a generic tool to merge geojson features take a look: https://github.com/abdurrahmanyildiz/geojson-feature-merger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not find one option when reading https://gdal.org/programs/ogrmerge.html

> **-single** If specified, all input vector layers will be merged into a single one.

Then do:

```
 ogrmerge -single -o merged.json *.json
```

How to merge just geometries but not attributes is worth another question. I do not believe it is possible with ogrmerge.

Comment: If you need to merge features, I have created a generic tool to merge geojson features take a look: https://github.com/abdurrahmanyildiz/geojson-feature-merger